# elixir Bson decoder failing on utf8 > 16#FF

Tags: mongodb, utf-8, bson, elixir

I am reading mongodb and using Bson.decoder(data). Along the way, the data becomes a list of tuples that includes {"unitˊs", 1}. String.to_atom("unitˊs") fails apparently because the 5th char is "MODIFIER LETTER ACUTE ACCENT (U+02CA)" with

`** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_atom("unitˊs", :utf8)`

and http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#binary_to_atom-2 notes
`binary_to_atom(Binary, utf8) will fail if the binary contains Unicode characters greater than 16#FF`

Are there any suggested work arounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any workarounds until Erlang 18 which will support the full unicode ranges for atoms. So the best option is to not convert it to an atom right now.

Comment: In the end, it was adequate to just drop anything > 0x00ff and did the following: `for(n<-String.to_char_list(k), n<256, do: n)|>to_string|>String.to_atom`